# calling a procedure when a button is pressed

Tags: position, command, label, spinner, kivy

i thought this would be easy but here i am!!

I was to call a procedure when the button is pressed and display the result on a label

```
class DSFRSapp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        i = Image(source='DSFRSLogo.png',
                  allow_stretch=True,
                  pos_hint = ({'center_x':0.5, 'y': .25}))
        spinner = Spinner(
text='Pick a Station',
values=('Appledore','Axminster','Bampton','Barnstaple','Bere Alston','Bideford','Bovey Tracey','Braunton','Bridgwater','Brixham','Buckfastleigh','Budleigh Salterton','Burnham on sea','Camels Head','Castle Cary','Chagford','Chard','Cheddar','Chulmleigh','Colyton','Combe Martin','Crediton','Crewkerne','Crownhill','Cullompton','Dartmouth','Dawlish','Exeter Danes Castle','Exeter Middlemoor','Exmouth','Frome','Glastonbury','Greenbank','Hartland','Hatherleigh','Holsworthy','Honiton','Ilfracombe','Ilminster','Ivybridge','Kingsbridge','Kingston','Lundy Island','Lynton','Martock','Minehead','Modbury','Moretonhampstead','Nether Stowey','Newton Abbot','North Tawton','Okehampton','Ottery St Mary','Paignton','Plympton','Plymstock','Porlock','Princetown','Salcombe','Seaton','Shepton Mallet','Sidmouth','Somerton','South Molton','Street','Taunton','Tavistock','Teignmouth','Tiverton','Topsham','Torquay','Torrington','Totnes','USAR','Wellington','Wells','Williton','Wincanton','Witheridge','Wiveliscombe','Woolacombe','Yelverton','Yeovil'),
size_hint=(None, None),
size=(150, 44),
pos_hint = ({'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.35}))
        b = Button(text="Search For Incidents",size_hint=(None, None),
                   pos_hint =({'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.25}),
                   size=(150, 44))
        LblRes = Label(text="Results will display here",
                       pos_hint =({'center_x':0.5, 'y': 0.15}),
                       size_hint=(600,100),color=(1,1,1,1),font_size=35)
        b.bind(on_press=FindIncident(Spinner.text))
        self.root.add_widget(spinner)
        self.root.add_widget(LblRes)
        self.root.add_widget(i)
        self.root.add_widget(b)
        return
def FindIncident( sStation ):
    webpage = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")#main page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
    incidents = soup.find(id="CollapsiblePanel1") #gets todays incidents panel
    Links = [] #create list call Links

    for line in incidents.find_all('a'): #get all hyperlinks
        Links.append("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/"+line.get('href')) #loads links into Links list while making them full links
    n = 0
    e = len(Links)
    if e == n: #if no links available no need to continue
       print("No Incidents Found Please Try Later")
       sys.exit(0)

    sFound = False
    while n < e: #loop through links to find station
        if sFound: #if the station has been found stop looking
            sys.exit(0)
        webpage = request.urlopen(Links[n]) #opens link in list)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage) #loads webpage
        if soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r'{}'.format(sStation))) == []:#check if returned value is found
        #do nothing leaving blank gave error
            a = "1" #this is pointless but stops the error
        else:
            print(soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r'{}'.format(sStation)))) #output result
            WebLink = Links[n]
            sFound = True # to avoid un needed goes through the loop process
        n=n+1 # moves counter to next in list
    if not sFound: #after looping process if nothing has been found output nothing found
        print("nothing found please try again later")
    return;

if __name__ =="__main__":
    DSFRSapp().run()
```

so when the button is pressed to call FindIncident using the spinner text as the string. That way it can search for the station and instead of print i will put the results in the label, possibly with a link to the website too.

any help would be great!

Raif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> b.bind(on_press=FindIncident(Spinner.text))

You need to pass a function as the argument to `bind`. You aren't passing FindIncident, you're *calling* it and passing the result...which is None.

Try

```
from functools import partial
b.bind(on_press=partial(FindIncident, spinner.text))
```

Also declare FindIncident as  `def FindIncident( sStation, *args ):`, as bind will automatically pass extra arguments. You could also do the same thing with a lambda function.

Be careful with your code cases as well - at the moment you use `Spinner.text`, when you probably mean `spinner.text`, as you created a variable `spinner`.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I won't get to try it till Thursday but am sure it will bee great! Just quickly any idea why i can't see the label with the above code? Thanks again!